# Is mHandler.obtainMessage supposed to fire handleMessage(Message msg)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handlers

Second question of the day! (Sorry, Newbie)

I'm trying to create a separate thread, and in that thread I need to be able to send information back to the UI thread. For this, I went ahead and created a new Handler Class:

```
private static class nHandler extends Handler{
    private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mTarget;
    public nHandler(MainActivity context){
        mTarget = new WeakReference<MainActivity>((MainActivity) context);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){ Log.d("Something", "It got here")}
    }
```

In my main activity class I have a private static nHandler mHandler; I then created a handler in my onCreate() using mHandler = new nHandler(this);

When I create my other thread, and it runs I create a handler object and set it to the one I passed in the constructor. In this other class I then have a function:

```
private synchronized void setState(int state){
    //lets add some logging
    mState = state;
    //Give the handler something so the Main Activity Updates
    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.HANDLER_CHANGE_SERVER_STATUS, state, -1);
}
```

But in the Log I don't see my log come up. I may not completely understand how handlers are supposed to work, so if you think that is the case can you help me understand them and get it working right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok Guys.....

Well I figured it out.

Anytime you do

`mHandler.obtainMessage()` make sure you include `.sendToTarget();`

So in the end it looked like:

```
mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.HANDLER_CHANGE_SERVER_STATUS, state, -1).sendToTarget();
```

I'm leaving this question up in case someone else Google's for it

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the obtained message.

```
 mHandler.sendMessage( mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.HANDLER_CHANGE_SERVER_STATUS, state, -1));
```